# Decoder data:image/png;base64 com PHP

Tags: php

Preciso que gere a imagem convertida pela string base64. tenho o código abaixo, porem ao acessar via navegador, gera diversos caracteres inválidos.

```
<?php
    $string  = 'hOjo6uPnmm1Gr1fT29tLU1IQoinLUMbdAJJvNEgqFOH78uJxbGI/HEQQBlUpFJpNBrVbzwAMPYDQaAdi3bx+PP/74511dXa9lMpk0MAb8YAWw3yIAcmQGyubOcPFAiAmCYKmqqnryoYceutnr9fLee+/x2WefUVNTQ2Njo+ygSaf.......';

    $decoded = base64_decode($string);

    echo $decoded;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário que seu servidor "informe" para o navegador que ele (o servidor) está enviando uma imagem, para isso é necessário incluir o cabeçalho `Content-Type: image/jpeg`, por exemplo.

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $decoded;
```

[Lista de MimeTypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) que você pode utilizar.

Comment: Boa. Era isso mesmo. Obrigado.